# How can I show specific screens to different type of user with React Native & Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building a react native application with Expo and Firebase. I have two type of users, gymnasts and coaches. I want to show different screens for each user.

The users are stored in a Firestore collection and i'm fetching their data and performing a query to conditionally render the screens. However the code is not working and weither I log in with the role gymnast or coach, it only shows the screens for the Gymnast (which I've build first)

Can someone show me where i've made a mistake and how to navigate/conditionally render correctly?

```js
export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [gymnastLoggedIn, setGymnastLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [coachLoggedIn, setCoachLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      } else {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("role", "==", "Gymnast");
        setGymnastLoggedIn(true);
        setCoachLoggedIn(false);
      } else if (user) {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("role", "==", "Coach");
        setCoachLoggedIn(true);
        setGymnastLoggedIn(false);
      } else {
        setGymnastLoggedIn(false);
        setCoachLoggedIn(false);
      }
    });
  }, [user]);

  if (gymnastLoggedIn == true) {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                let iconName;

                if (route.name === "Home") {
                  iconName = focused ? "ios-home" : "ios-home-outline";
                } else if (route.name === "Goals") {
                  iconName = focused
                    ? "checkmark-circle"
                    : "checkmark-circle-outline";
                } else if (route.name === "Skills") {
                  iconName = focused ? "flame" : "flame";
                } else if (route.name === "Competition") {
                  iconName = focused ? "folder" : "folder-open";
                } else if (route.name === "Profile") {
                  iconName = focused ? "person" : "person";
                }

                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
              },

              tabBarActiveTintColor: "#314466",
              tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#665c5a",
            })}
          >
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeGymnast}
              options={{ headerShown: true }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Goals"
              component={GoalsGymnast}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Skills"
              component={SkillsGymnast}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Competition"
              component={CompetitionGymnast}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Profile"
              component={Profile}
              options={{ headerShown: true }}
            />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    } else if (coachLoggedIn == true) {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                let iconName;

                if (route.name === "HomeCoach") {
                  iconName = focused ? "ios-home" : "ios-home-outline";
                } else if (route.name === "GymnastsCoach") {
                  iconName = focused ? "at" : "at";
                } else if (route.name === "GroupsCoach") {
                  iconName = focused ? "contacts" : "contacts";
                } else if (route.name === "ProfileCoach") {
                  iconName = focused ? "person" : "person";
                }

                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
              },

              tabBarActiveTintColor: "#314466",
              tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#665c5a",
            })}
          >
            <Tab.Screen
              name="HomeCoach"
              component={HomeCoach}
              options={{ headerShown: true }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="GymnastsCoach"
              component={GymnastsCoach}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="GroupsCoach"
              component={GroupsCoach}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="ProfileCoach"
              component={ProfileCoach}
              options={{ headerShown: true }}
            />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
  } else {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignUp"
            component={SignUp}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="PageOne"
            component={PageOne}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return all the users who have role Gymnast and same goes for the Coach role.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("role", "==", "Gymnast");
```

Instead you should create a document for each user in the users collection and store their role as shown below:

```
users -> {userId} // user ID from Firebase Authentication

{
  role: "gymnast",
  ...otherUserData
}
```

Then you can read their document after user logs in as shown below:

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState("");

// only one useEffect here

useEffect(() => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
      const userDocSnap = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get();

      if (userDocSnap.exists) {
        const userData = userDocSnap.data();

      } else {
        console.log("user document missing")
      }
    } else {
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Then instead of `if (gymnastLoggedIn == true)` in your components, use `if (role === "gymnast")` and render Gymnast component if true.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been coding very long, but the solution doesn't fully work. When I tried this way I get an error that says: "Can't find variable: role" and when I try user.role or userData.role the navigation doesn't work.

Comment: @JosineD58 my bad, it should be `userRole` as on top we have `const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState("");`

Comment: Thank you! One more stupid question. Where in the useEffect do you setUserRole. When I put it beneath const userData as follows: setUserRole(userData) that doesn't work.

Comment: @JosineD58 it should be after userData. `setUserRole(userData.role`

Comment: The conditional rendering now works, thank you very much! If you have the time could you also please answer my follow up question. Ever since this part worked, my logout function: const logout = () => {firebase.auth.signOut()}} doesn't do anything anymore. Is there an easy fix?

Comment: @JosineD58 can you provide more details such as screenshot of errors and relevant code? Also it might be best to post a new question with the details as others will be able to take a look as well.

Comment: Yes, will do! Here is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73672246/react-native-firebase-logout-function-doesnt-work-after-login-based-on-user-typ